# Selenium / Raspberry Pi 3 - Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi3

I want to run a Python 3 script on my Raspberry Pi and do stuff with it. The script works just fine on my Mac, however I want it to run 24/7 and the Pi is more energy efficient. Not to mention I need my Mac for other things.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('www.website.com')
```

I am running Raspbian Jesse and have installed Iceweasel (installed today through command line, V 45) and geckodriver (0.18.0).

Running the script throws the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Which line is giving you that exception? Selenium version? Firefox version?

Comment: The line is 

browser = webdriver.Firefox() 

Firefox is 45.9.0 (iceweasel) I installed it just now, it did not come on the machine before. Selenium is 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem. For me, installing an older version of selenium fixed the problem.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall selenium
sudo pip3 install selenium==3.3.2
```

Works for me on Raspbian Jessie with Firefox 45.9.0, geckodriver v0.18.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest Selenium, Firefox, and geckodriver.

Firefox:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr --upgrade
```

Selenium:

```
pip install selenium --upgrade
```

Mozilla no longer publishes arm7 geckodriver binaries, but there are instructions to crosscompile it for arm7 from another platform [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/ARM.html) and regular building instructions [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Building.html). The first step is downloading the source:

```
curl https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/archive/tip.zip/testing/ > testing.zip
unzip testing.zip
```

Or if v26 is sufficient, I've compiled it for arm7 [here](https://github.com/Tahlor/geckodriver): https://github.com/Tahlor/geckodriver