# How to fix (selenium) error "unable to find a matching set of capabilities" on raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I want to make selenium work on my raspberry pi 3 b+ which has raspbian lite installed in order to refresh a browser page. But I receive the error  "unable to find a matching set of capabilities" even though I have installed the newest versions of firefox-esr, selenium, python3 and geckodriver.

I tried downloading all different kinds of geckodriver versions, also python versions but for now I am stuck at the newest versions for selenium > 3.11, firefox-esr 60.0, geckodriver 26.0 (I also copied geckodriver to usr/bin) and python3 > 3.14 - according to this site it should be working fine?? https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

```
try
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("localhost:3000")
    driver.refresh()
except Error as err:
    print(err)
```

While I tried out different geckodriver versions I also encountered the error "[errno 8] exec format error" besides the most recent one - "unable to find a matching set of capabilities"

One thing that bugs me is that sometimes geckodriver are downloadable with some armhf support but sometimes there is only linux 32 bit or linux 64 bit an option... I think raspberry pi 3 needs support for the armlv7 architecture or something??

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a Pi 3 as well, and I get this error, but seemingly randomly (it's on a cron job and usually works).

Comment: Upgrading geckodriver solved it, kind of annoying they don't publish the arm7 binaries any more
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400232/selenium-raspberry-pi-3-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities/60019725#60019725